# How to pass an input from c++ function to the main function

Tags: c++, function, input

i want to take an input from c++ function and return it to the main function
, i've already tried to do it but the function returns zero , any idea ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int input( int x);
int main()
{
    int number;
    input(number);
    cout<<number;

}
int input (int x)
{
    cin>>x;  
    return  x;
}
```

Comment: C++ uses a pass-by-value system. In order to let cin write to the variable you want, you need to declare `int input(int &x)` which tells the compiler to pass a reference to your variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass by reference

```
 void input (int & x)
 {
   cin>>x;  
 }
```

or use the return value

```
int main()
{
  int number;
  number = input();
  cout<<number;
}

int input ()
{
  cin>>x;  
  return  x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function to make it take `x` by reference:

```
void input (int& x)
{
    cin>>x;  
}
```

This way, you don't even need to return x, because your function will update its value as it is passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's get it from the begining :
It any function, all its variables are temporary and only accessible in this function's scope unless you use a pointer or a reference(c++ only)

So what happen when you call your function is that a copy of `number`'s is created into `x`

Also, the return statement of a function is used to... return values! Yeah, weird uh?

So actually you don't even need to send any parameter to your function and just take its result :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int input();
int main()
{
    int number = input(); // Takes what the return statement gives
    cout<<number;

}
int input ()
{
    int x;
    cin>>x;  
    return  x;
}
```

Here's another way by using c++'s references :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void input( int& x);
int main()
{
    int number;
    input(number);
    cout<<number;

}
int input (int& x)//Takes number's address
{
    cin>>x;
}
```